# Web API passing Object to a Get method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

is there a way to pass an object as a parameter in a Get method in Web API? I have the following case:

In my Web.API project the Get method looks like that:

```
public IEnumerable<ArticleMetaData> GetComponentXMLByDate(ComponentRequest request)
        {
           // Some logic here
            return articleMeta;
        }
```

My ComponentRequest object looks like:

```
public class ComponentRequest
    {        
        public string startdate { get; set; }
        public string enddate { get; set; }       
        public string pagenumber { get; set; }
        public string pagesize { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to call it this way:

> http://mydomain.com/api/values/?startdate=121922&enddate=063020&pagenumber=2&pagesize=100

In the method ComponentRequest request is coming as null. If I change the method to accept multiple string parameters instead of the object it works fine.

Am I missing something in my setup?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think that

```
public IEnumerable<ArticleMetaData> GetComponentXMLByDate([FromUri]ComponentRequest request)
{
    // Some logic here
    return articleMeta;
}
```

should work.

Mike Stall has a good article on [how-webapi-does-parameter-binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `[FromUri]` attribute.

Look at the the following question.
[ASP.NET MVC Web Api Get Not Mapping QueryString To Strongly Typed Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589988/asp-net-mvc-web-api-get-not-mapping-querystring-to-strongly-typed-parameter)