# Passing an object via AJAX to an API MVC C#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api

I am trying to pass an object to my API but it keeps showing the object as NULL in the API.

My Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: url,
   data: tranData,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(response){
   var itemcount = response.itemsCount;
   var dataReturned = response.data;
}});
```

My API Method:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("Api/ReportApi/SummaryReport")]
        public IHttpActionResult SummaryReport(JObject tranData)
        {     

            dynamic oData = tranData;
            BankTransactionsViewModelResults transactions = new BankTransactionsViewModelResults();

            transactions = oData;

            var summarisedTransactions = SummariseResults(transactions.BankTransactionsViewModelList, "Test Ref");

            var response = new
            {
                data = summarisedTransactions,
                itemsCount = summarisedTransactions.Count(),
            };

            return Request.GetOKRequest(response);
        }
```

The object I am trying to pass:

```
[{"id":16,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"DEPOSIT","reference":"TEST10a","description":"TEST10d","amount":600000.0,"balance":600000.0,"tranDate":1494374400000},

{"id":17,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"WITHDRAWAL","reference":"TEST10b","description":"TEST10d","amount":-400000.0,"balance":200000.0,"tranDate":1494460800000},

{"id":18,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"DEPOSIT","reference":"TEST10c","description":"TEST10c","amount":700000.0,"balance":900000.0,"tranDate":1494547200000},

{"id":19,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"TRANSFER","reference":"TEST10d","description":"TEST10d","amount":-600000.0,"balance":300000.0,"tranDate":1494633600000},

{"id":20,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"DEPOSIT","reference":"TEST10e","description":"TEST10e","amount":800000.0,"balance":1100000.0,"tranDate":1494720000000},

{"id":21,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"WITHDRAWAL","reference":"TEST10f","description":"TEST10f","amount":-800000.0,"balance":300000.0,"tranDate":1494806400000},

{"id":22,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"DEPOSIT","reference":"TEST10g","description":"TEST10g","amount":900000.0,"balance":1.2E7,"tranDate":1494892800000},

{"id":23,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"TRANSFER","reference":"TEST10h","description":"TEST10h","amount":-400000.0,"balance":800000.0,"tranDate":1494979200000},

{"id":24,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"DEPOSIT","reference":"TEST10i","description":"TEST10i","amount":800000.0,"balance":1.6E7,"tranDate":1495065600000},

{"id":25,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"TRANSFER","reference":"TEST10j","description":"TEST10j","amount":-800000.0,"balance":800000.0,"tranDate":1495152000000},

{"id":26,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"DEPOSIT","reference":"TEST10k","description":"TEST10k","amount":900000.0,"balance":1.7E7,"tranDate":1495238400000},

{"id":27,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1,"agentId":1,"tranType":"WITHDRAWAL","reference":"TEST10l","description":"TEST10l","amount":-700000.1,"balance":0.0,"tranDate":1495324800000}]
```

How can I pass this to my API? `tranData` is appearing as null but before being sent I can see the data is there...? I get this data from an external API call and get it from the response:

```
var tranData = JSON.parse(req.response);
```

Comment: See this [How to pass json POST data to Web API method as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object/20226220#20226220)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass json POST data to Web API method as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to use `HttpGet` to complete the request, you will have to use strictly typed object like mentioned in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571195/web-api-passing-object-to-a-get-method). And you may change your method signature to the following

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Api/ReportApi/SummaryReport")]
public IHttpActionResult SummaryReport([FromUri]YourCustomClass tranData)
{
    // your code
}
```

A better alternative will be to use `HttpPost`.
In that case you will have to use `JToken` not `JObject`. Here is how your signature will look like

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Api/ReportApi/SummaryReport")]
public IHttpActionResult SummaryReport([FromBody]JToken tranData)
{
    BankTransactionsViewModelResults transactions = tranData.ToObject<BankTransactionsViewModelResults>();

    // other processing code
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a class with 
id,accountId,clientId,agentId and so on what you are passing

Next create Object of class

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("Api/ReportApi/SummaryReport")]
    public IHttpActionResult SummaryReport(Class classobj)
    { your code here  }
```

after in ajax
you need send json data Format

like tranData{{"id":16,"accountId":11111000010,"clientId":1 like so on}