# WebApi not binding to (reasonably) simple model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

At the risk of asking a noob question, I am trying to test a url to post to a webapi endpoint that it should have model bound to, were this MVC:

```
    public ReturnModel GetSomeInformation( ValidationPackage validationPackage)
    {
        return new ReturnModel();
    }
```

where ValidationPackage is something like:

```
public class ValidationPackage : BaseValidationPackage
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
}
```

So when I simply try to test this or demo it for my iOS guy that needs it, the following doesn't bind:

http://[local]/api/meet/GetInformation?ClubId=152

Should I change the method signature to this, then it all works fine:

```
public ReturnModel GetSomeInformation( int clubId) {...}
```

But somehow I was under the impression that my first version should have worked and that I'm doing something wrong as I was under the impression that webapi was just an implementation of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the Web API will bind query string parameters to primitive types and request body content to complex types

The model binder is expecting a `ValidationPackage` object in the request body, but you're passing a primitive in the query string.

You could have the following as your post body:

```
{
  "ClubId": 152
}
```

If you need to pass it in the query string you'll need to override the default behavior using the `[FromUri]` attribute:

```
public ReturnModel GetSomeInformation([FromUri] ValidationPackage validationPackage)
{
    return new ReturnModel();
}
```

There is more information on the parameter binding functionality of the Web Api [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx) and you can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589988/asp-net-mvc-web-api-get-not-mapping-querystring-to-strongly-typed-parameter).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that to no more avail... To clarify, I'm not crazy though, it SHOULD bind to a more complex object once I get this right?

Comment: In my tests it all works fine, but I really wanted to see it work through the URL... I didn't necessarily want the iOS dev calling these to be concerned about knowing that ClubId lived in ValidationPackage

Comment: As far as I'm aware if you have the `[FromUri]` attribute it should work. If you set a breakpoint, what does the model come through as, is it just null?

Comment: I just realized I was doing something stupid elsewhere, FromUri did work and I didn't debug it correctly last time... Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for model binding in MVC (and Web API) simple types (`string`, `int`, `Guid`, etc...) are bound from the query string. Objects, on the other hand, will be bound using the Body of the request. You can change this behavior in a per parameter basis using the [`FromBodyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) or [`FromUriAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.fromuriattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) (depending on your need):

```
public ReturnModel GetSomeInformation([FromUri]ValidationPackage validationPackage)
{
    return new ReturnModel();
}
```